# Create Empty Form In Jdeveloper 12c

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

[image]I am using J Developer 12 c. I want to create form but without any data fetched in.I want user to enter detail in form for submission.I have tried all online solution but they are for J Developer 11.I am not able to fetch an empty form.

When I run my form it automatically fetch record from the table.I have tried use create insert but i want form to be automatically fetched with new record every time page is run.

Comment: JDeveloper 11 resources will in most cases work in 12c too. Did you try them before giving up on them?

Comment: thanks@Joe yes i did,few features are completely new in 12c.i am new to adf almost found nowhere my exact solution.i understood what u said but i want smth else.if i provide sumbit to all 3 pages and on 4 summary page provide a single commit it dsnt save data to database.this is why i have to commit on all 3 pages.i know i am missing something which might be a basic thing but i am struck badly.i also created a new view with 3 eo of tables whose summary i wanted on 4 page and provided commit button only on last page but not working.sorry not able to share s/s

Comment: @Joe:@Joe:I am  struck again need your help.I have created a table with id as primary key with  database and sequence and in EO changed attribute as DBSequence which works fine.But i have other column which is customerNumber in this i am creating sequence and concatenating with a prefix and storing in varchar column custnumber.but when i change it to dbsequence it doesnot allow me to update existing record and throw invalid number exception.please suggest what should i do so that i can also update existing customer records.

Comment: check the docs and make sure you have a trigger to set the value for the custNumber https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14023/oracle/jbo/domain/DBSequence.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a CreateInsert action in your task flow on the way into you page. This will clear the fields for data entry. Look [here](http://deepakcs.blogspot.com/2013/01/create-adf-input-form-without-first.html).

You need to understand the difference between commit and submit. You want to submit the pages - clicking a submit button - and then the page is processed and the EO/VOs are updated **in memory**.

The Commit operation writes the in-memory changes to the datasource (database). So, you can submit pages 1-3 then using the same data control the fields will be populated with the entered data on page 4. Now the user can commit the changes. The Commit action is located in the operations for the AppModule-DataControl.

This is the power of the ADF Data Control. Changes to fields are cached in memory and are available to any page and then those changes can be committed when you choose. Note, the Task Flow can [control the transaction itself](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adf-task-flow-trans-fund-v1-0-1723395.pdf).

Sounds like you need to learn the basics of ADF. I suggest this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071622543) and [this](http://joestechland.com/oracle/oracle/adf-desktop/) set of resources I maintain for my students and [these](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/jdeveloper-reviewrguide-086026.html).

And, if you will be doing a lot of ADF development, it is well worth your time to take our [ADF course](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&get_params=dc:D76564,clang:EN).

(It also seems you are unaware of how stack overflow works. When you get an response that answers you question, you up-vote the answer, so it encourages those of us taking our time to answer you question for free to continue doing so. Please note that I answered your original question and Shay reinforced that answer.
And I have now answered your second question, and provided links to resources to help you go further.

Comment: well i already went through the article but i am working on 12c and the options for action executables have changed.however i have finally made the form empty by using create insert in task flow.but i have connected three forms the first form is master and second and third is child form.The problem here is that i have created a chain for these 3 forms i manged to get the first master form as empty but then when i click next i want the second child form also to be created with empty record so as user can insert detail but it is coming greyed out.@Joe.From where i can share snapshot btw.

Comment: If your navigation between the 3 pages defined through a taskflow (which it should) then you can add a createInsert operation to the taskflow navigation before each page - and use the correct createInsert for the VO used on that page.

Comment: well yes i did that but the problem is that i want a review page which is 4 page in train and then if user find correct he can commit it and if not he can edit it.I am very confused since if i add commit on each page(individual table)then on review no one can change it.and if i add commit on final page it is not throwing fk violation error because without commiting master table i cant commit other 2 table.also i created a view object which is based on 3 entity object(those 3 tables)but on review  i cannot commit or edit it.I don know where am i missing.please help @ShayShmeltzer

Comment: Joe, would you have any insight into [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/toy-databases-for-class-examples-homeworks)?

Answer (score 0):

I already marked the correct answer however my second question where i was unable to commit on review page which fetch data from 3 vo i got solution thanks to http://www.baigzeeshan.com/2010/11/avoiding-jbo-26048-during-commit-in.html.Actually the first Eo is master for rest 2 Eo so it would ideally allow me to commit detail data only after i commit the master.Now i found the blog and it suggested me to do changes in association and add behaviour for composite association and cascade update for key attribute.Now i can directly commit on my last review page and navigate through task flow easily without using commit on eac individual page.thanks all who helped me.